# How to create a OS-independent client-server application on Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I have been following the official tutorials about Sockets ([link to the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)); however, I have not been able to 'link' two PC's with two different operating systems, there are not errors shown.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this entirely on Java, or if there is any existent library out there that does it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Post the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: Posat your errors? what **ARE** errors not shown?

Comment: Most likely, you're running into a firewall.

Comment: How do I check if the firewall is affecting it in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Java should already by platform, OS and hardware independent.  You may have network issues?

Comment: How could I test that?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  What are the devices you used, and what is the code you ran on each?